# Can I break a lease if there is construction noise outside that is not under control of my landlord?

Tags: noise

I moved in knowing that there is construction outsides. However, what I did not know is that this construction site would violate the law and start construction as early as 5:30 AM. They have been fined twice by the city of Seattle. If they keep ignoring the law and start construction early, can I break my lease? I know it's not my landlord's responsibility, but it's insufferable for me because I cannot sleep.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't break a lease for a problem that is not caused by your landlord. You can, however, file repeated complaints, as can others in your building and, presumably, adjacent buildings. Written letters may be necessary if the online [complaint facility](http://www.seattle.gov/sdci/codes/make%C2%A0a-property-or-building-complaint) doesn't work. If they respond that the project has an exemption, that is unfortunate for you. Do not complain to the police (they do not deal with construction noise) – instead, complain to Construction and Inspections Compliance.

Comment: The question said that the construction company has been fined twice by the city, presumably for violating noise regulations.  It doesn't sound like it has an exemption.

Comment: I avoid making such presumptions, knowing that the city may well have issued a fine for something else. The point is to file a complaint and get a clear indication of whether this is permitted noise, and determine why the city hasn't taken more aggressive action if it's not permitted.